# Install LibreOffice on Solaris without root access?

Tags: software-installation, solaris, non-root-user, libreoffice

How can I install `LibreOffice` on `Solaris` without root access.

I just need to use `libreoffice` on the command line and do some conversions between `Word` and `RTF`.

Is this possible to do this just in my home directory without root access?

Comment: Install from what?  Source code?  SVR4 package(s)?  IPS package(s)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle whatever is best

Answer (score 0):

Unless you compile it from source it is not possible to install LibreOffice by unpacking it on your home folder. In fact from the official website, they only provide binaries for Linux, Mac and Windows.

This was previously done with OpenOffice during Sun Microsytems time.